# Download speed from AmazonAWS

Tags: networking, download, amazon-web-services

I've noticed that download speed to my laptop (via Fibre broadband) is very slow (3-400kbps) from AmazonAWS when downloading the [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/hdp/downloads/) HDP environment (VMWare OVA file, 2.5gb in size).

When downloading the same file to an Azure VM it downloads at 30-40 Mbps to the VM. I can then download it from Azure at 2-2.5 Mbps. This knocks an hour (approx) off the download time.

Is this solely because of the location of the AmazonAWS content ?

I don't think this is just the Hortonworks images, as I've noticed it on other downloads that come via AmazonAWS. MSDN doesn't have an issue as I can download from MSDN directly at 2-4 Mbps.

Comment: so depending on what you said, when you download from AmazonAWS servers, your downloading speed is lower than when you download from Azure server. is my understanding true?

Comment: Downloading from AmazonAWS to home is slower than downloading from AmazonAWS to Azure, then from Azure to home.

Comment: Servers can limit their speed for users who want to connect them and download something. but they can also break the limitation for other services like Azure as you said. so imagine that you have a speedy car. you'r going from A to B but there is speed limits on the way so you can't drive faster (from AmazonAWS to your home!). but you may have the same car and want to drive from A to C, here there is no speed limits and you can drive as fast as you want (from AmazonAWS to Azure). so it can be a server side problem.

Comment: Your fiber connection wouldn't be Verizon, by chance, would it?

Comment: Ok, well it's a good use-case for Azure then. Download staging.... Fibre connection is from Zen Internet (in the UK, using the BT infrastructure but no throttling).